# Can I use a library which references an unavailable assembly, if it's not used?

Tags: .net, 64-bit

I have a library X, which has a class C which used component Y.
However, Y isn't available in 64 bit, so it's been replaced by component Z, but I want to still use Y when available.

So I would like to reference Y and Z and then have

C.vb:

```
#If 32bit then
Class C
// implementation of C using Y
End Class
#End If
```

C64.vb

```
#If 64bit then
Public Class C
// implementation of C using Z
End Class
#End If
```

*Note:* C-style Comments due to highlighting errors with vb comments.

The problem, as I see it, is that I will have a reference to Y in the 64 bit version(it's a COM object, so it would be an interop assembly, if that makes a difference). Assuming Y is not called from anywhere in the code, will I be able to instantiate C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're okay on several levels.  The #if ensures that your code doesn't use any types from Y, the compiler will actually remove the assembly reference from the final assembly.  Even if you did have references to Y types in your code, they can actually be JIT compiled because you *do* have valid metadata for it.  You've got the interop assembly.

The only thing you can't do is create the COM object and call its methods.  You can use a regular if rather than #if.  Allowing you to avoid building separate assemblies. Testing IntPtr.Size is a good way to find out if you are running in 64-bit mode.

Comment: Thank you, Hans. Y has some functionality which Z doesn't have, and I think it's possible that in some cases I could want to use the 32-bit assembly on a 64-bit system. I would need to build a specific 32-bit version for this, wouldn't I?

Comment: Just set the Platform Target setting of the EXE project to x86 and you can always use Y, even on a 64-bit operating system.

Comment: Thank you very much, Hans. You're really helpful. I was asking this because in this case I'd lose the advantages of using a regular "if" instead of "#if" (I have to maintain both versions anyway).